# iOS - Get local date & time in International format and English language

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdateformatter

I am trying to get the user's local Date & Time using the below code

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat: @"dd MMM yyyy"];
[dateFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

NSDateFormatter *timeFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[timeFormatter setDateFormat: @"HH:mm"];
[timeFormatter setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone localTimeZone]];

self.appearedOnDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
self.appearedOnTime = [timeFormatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]];
```

It returns correct values, but in the language set on users device.
For example, in a case where user has Simplified Chinese set on his device, I am getting the output as

```
24 3月 2015 --- 22:13
```

How can I get the local time in English language ?

I guess this happens only in iOS8 and not on iOS6, but I am not sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You might add the following code before print your output.

```
 [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers];
 NSLocale *locale = [[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
 [timeFormatter setLocale:locale];
```

Comment: That was really quick! You saved my day! Thanks a lot! Although did not understand the purpose of calling [NSLocale availableLocaleIdentifiers], could you explain ?